# HTML5: How do I capture a picture from the webcam?

Tags: html

What's the simplest (for coder and for user) and most backward-compatible/unbreakable way to capture a picture from the user's webcam in the browser?

More questions:
Is there a de-facto standard webservice for doing this?
Are there any related standards like microformats or other optional code indicated by "best practices"?

Comment: I'm writing this as a comment, not an answer because I'm short on time. WebRTC allows your browser to ask for webcam access. You can set the video to a canvas and copy one frame as an image. I'd recommend this blog entry: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of options on this...

1. getUserMedia() which is the new HTML5 method for accessing a users webcam and doing things with the image data. This is ONLY for modern browsers and currently is supported in Chrome, but I expect you will see it soon in the others. The method works great and is SUPER easy to use once you read through the docs.
2. Flash. Flash has always been good at this stuff and you can easily create a method for snapping a photo and sending the data to javascript or php for processing.